# Are aria attributes in open and close buttons for native dialog elements necessary?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

Are aria attributes like aria-controls necessary on buttons that open and close a native dialog element?
All examples always execute a dialog.showModal() directly, but isn't the reference to the dialog element missing here?

Example on Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Wouldn't an aria-controls="mydialog" be correct on the button element, just as it is on the disclosure pattern?

https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/

Is then additionally aria-expanded on the button necessary to describe the status of the dialog?

Otherwise it will not be recognized what the button is for.

Example Code with aria-controls atribute in button:

```js
const myDialog = document.getElementById('mydialog');
const dialogTrigger = document.getElementById('mydialogtrigger');

dialogTrigger.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  myDialog.showModal();
});
```

```html
<dialog id="mydialog">this is the dialog</dialog>
<button id="mydialogtrigger" aria-controls="mydialog">open dialog</button>
```